# Apache 2.4 not using the new DocumentRoot, not serving the static content

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-13.10

This is in connection with this question:
[Apache doesn't use DocumentRoot after upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10 (Uses default page that says "It works!")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841609/apache-doesnt-use-documentroot-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-13-10-uses-default-pa)

I ma working with 2.4.6 version. After changing the DocumentRoot, when I run apache2 -S, I get the values of Default virtual host, i.e. the DocumentRoot is "/var/www/.

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
     default server 127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost 127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost 127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl 
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
```

The document root is:

```
DocumentRoot /home/me/my_git/my_project
```

My Directory permissions are:

```
<Directory "/home/me/my_git/my_project">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory />
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI +MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I need to know the reason of this behaviour and how to correct it, my web page is displayed as a plain text. Please let me know if any other detail is needed

Comment: I have to make the project root folder as the DocumentRoot. I have changed the contents of 000-default.conf and apache2.conf (just copied the Directory tag here)

Comment: Ok, so you can view your project files (as plain texte), it means the DocumentRoot is applied, isn't it? the file you see are the one present in `/home/me/my_git/my_project`? and what are theses files? html files, php files? what should happen if it were working? If it is php, what is your apache-php configuration?